# Is there a way to display only the Day, Month and Year using PHP from a MSSQL Datetime column?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, time, timezone

I have a column in my MSSQL table that was created using part of a PHP query:

```
order_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
```

And whenever a new table row is created, data is put into that column like so:

```
Apr 8 2014 9:52AM
```

I would like to display the above column data (Apr 8 2014 9:52AM) in a table using PHP. I would like to only display the month, the day, and the year, and to not display the `9:52AM`.

I am doing this because the 9:52AM is incorrect for my timezone and is supposed to be 10:52AM.

I unfortunately do not have access to my SQL CPanel, so I will not be able to change the timezone universally from there.

So if there is either a way to add 1 hour to the time when a new row is created, or to just not display the time when I `echo` the table data, that would be perfect.

Thank you for any help. I appreciate all help.

Comment: `$only_date=date("F d Y", strtotime($your_full_date));`

Comment: You can set the timezone in your PHP page itself during the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Cut the time from the last Space in the string

```
<?php

$str = "Apr 8 2014 9:52AM";
$date = substr($str, 0, strrpos( $str, ' '));

echo $date;

?>
```

Output

**Apr 8 2014**

Comment: No problem, done. Just to add to my answer it may not be a good idea  to add 1 hour as the clocks change. I suggest to check default timezone from PHPNET to keep in sync. --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php